# Simplifying $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{c_k}{f'(a_k)}$, where $f(x)=(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\cdots(x-a_n)$ and $\frac{1}{f(x)}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{c_k}{x-a_k}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose there are $n$ real values: $$ a_1, ..., a_n $$
And $$f(x)=(x-a_1)(x-a_2)...(x-a_n)$$

So that
$$\frac{1}{f(x)}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{c_k}{x-a_k}$$

How would I use the relation above to simplify

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{c_k}{f'(a_k)}$$

How and where should I start?

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial fraction decomposition. If all the $a_k$ are distinct, you can multiply the second equation with $x-a_m$ and then perform the limit $x\to a_m$ to get
$$
c_m=\lim_{x\to a_m}\frac{x-a_m}{f(x)-f(a_m)}=\frac1{f'(a_m)}.
$$
In consequence, you are asking about
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{f'(a_k)^2}.
$$
This for instance is the quotient of the linear and constant term of the resultant
$$
Res_x(f(x),f'(x)^2+t)
$$
as a polynomial in $t$.